# How to display data from different data source tables in a single table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have a couple of different tables in my Report, for demonstration purposes lets say that I have 1 data source that is Actual Invoice amounts and then I have another table that is Forecasted amounts.  Each table has several dimensions that are the same between them, let say Country, Region, Product Classification and Product.

What I want is to be able to display a table/matrix that pulls information from both of these data sources like this

```
Description              Invoice    Forecast    vs Forecast
USA                        300          325           92% 
    East                   150          175           86%
       Product Grouping 1  125          125          100%
           Product 1        50           75           67%
           Product 2        75           50          150%
       Product Grouping 3   25           50           50%
           Product 3        25           50           50%
    West                   150          150          100%
       Product Grouping 1   75          100           75%
           Product 1        25           50           50%
           Product 2        50           50          100%
       Product Grouping 3   75           50          150%
           Product 3        75           50          150%
```

I have not been able to figure out a way to combine the information from the multiple data source into a single matrix table, so any help would be appreciated.  The one thing that I did find was somebody hard coded the structure of the rows into a separate data source and then used DAX expressions to pull in the pieces of information into the columns, but I don't like this solution because the structure of the rows is not constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking about is a common part of the star schema: combining facts from different fact tables together into a single visual or report.

### What Not To Do (That You Might Be Tempted To)

What you don't want to do is combine the 2 fact tables into a single table in your Power BI data model. That's a lot of work and there's absolutely no need. Especially, since there are likely dimensions that the 2 fact tables do not have in common (e.g. actual amounts might be associated with a customer dimension, but forecast amounts wouldn't be).

What you also don't want to do is relate the 2 fact tables to each other in any way. Again, that's a lot of work. (Especially since there's no natural way to relate them at the row level.)

### What To Do

Generally, how you handle 2 fact tables is the same as you handle a single fact table. First, you have your dimensions (country, region, classification, product, date, customer). Then you load your fact tables, and join them to the dimensions. You do not join your fact tables to each other. You then create measures (i.e. DAX expressions).

When you want to combine measures from the two facts together in a single matrix, **you only use rows/columns that are meaningful to both fact tables**. For example, actual amounts might be associated with a customer, but forecast amounts aren't. So you can't include customer information in the matrix. Another possibility is that actual amounts are recorded each day, whereas forecasts were done for the whole month. In this situation, you could put month in your matrix (since that's meaningful to both), but you wouldn't want to use date because Power BI wouldn't know how to divide up forecasts to individual dates.

As long as you're only using dimensions & attributes that are meaningful to both fact tables, you can easily create a matrix as you envision above. Simply drag on the attributes you want, then add the measures (i.e. DAX expressions).

The Invoice & Forecast columns would both be measures. The two measures from different fact tables can be combined into a 3rd measure for the vs. Forecast measure. Everything will work as long as you're just using dimensions/attributes that mean something to both fact tables.

I don't see anything in your proposed pivot table that strikes me as problematic.

### Other Situations

If you have a situation where forecasts are at a month level and actual is at a date level, then you may be wondering how you'd relate them both to the same date dimension. This situation is called having different granularities, and there's a good article here I'd recommend reading that has advice: https://www.daxpatterns.com/handling-different-granularities/. Indeed, there's a whole section on comparing budget with revenue that you might find useful.

Finally, you mention that someone hard-coded the structure of the rows and used DAX expressions to build everything. This does, admittedly, sound like overkill. The goal with Power BI is flexibility. Once you have your facts, measures & dimensions, you can combine them in any way that makes sense. Hard-coding the rows eliminates that flexibility, and is a good clue that something isn't right. (Another good clue that something isn't right is when DAX expressions seem really complicated for something that should be easy)

---

I hope my answer helps. It's a general answer since your question is general. If you have specific questions about your specific situation, definitely post additional questions. (Sample data, a description of the model, the problem you're seeing, and what you want to see is helpful to get a good answer.)

If you're brand new to Power BI, data models, and the star schema, Alberto Ferrari and Marco Russo have an excellent book that I'd recommend reading to get a crash course: https://www.sqlbi.com/books/analyzing-data-with-microsoft-power-bi-and-power-pivot-for-excel/